# how to order hour:minute asc in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

```
           hours ---->>>> type:TIME
           08:20
           08:10
           08:15
           09:10
           08:12
```

How to sort this ASC?

I want these to be like these:

```
          hours

          08:10
          08:12
          08:15
          08:20
          09:10
```

I've tried this queries :

```
        SELECT * .... ORDER BY TIME(hours)
   AND another query:
        SELECT * .... ORDER BY (hours) ASC
```

both of these query will return this result :

```
        it returns this:
        08:10:00 
        08:15:00 
        09:10:00-------------->*****
        08:20:00
```

You see that ***** ?.
 why ??????

Thanks

Comment: What format is that column? Is it a string? or one of the date/time types?

Comment: its string 
shall I change it to date/time?

Comment: Yes. You want to use the [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) type.

Comment: I just tried . NOT WORKING
it return this:
08:10:00
08:15:00
09:10:00*******>>>>
08:12:00

Comment: I JUST EDITED my question , please read it again< thanks

Comment: It's not possible. Provide the complete query, the table schema and `INSERT` statements to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * .... ORDER BY TIME(hours) ASC
```

I assume your hours is a DateTime column, if is a varchar/char*/varchar2/Text column you can just use hours directly:

```
SELECT * .... ORDER BY hours ASC
```

Comment: `ASC` is assumed when no direction is provided